# Get grouped structure using argparse.ArgumentParser()

Tags: python, argparse

I'd like to translate something like:

```
test.py --group 1 --opt1 foo1 --opt2 bar1 \
        --group 2 --opt1 foo2 \
        --group 3 --opt1 foo3 --opt2 bar3 --opt3 baz3
```

into something like a dictionary (like Namespace):

```
{
  "1": {"opt1": "foo1", 
        "opt2": "bar1"},
  "2": {"opt1": "foo2"}, 
  "3": {"opt1": "foo3", 
        "opt2": "bar3",
        "opt3": "baz3"}
}
```

- The input can be another format if needed.
- I want to raise an error if other than (opt1, opt2, opt3) is used
- I should use argparse.ArgumentParser().

Can you help?

Comment: What have you done so far? See this to know how to ask a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I guess too with a external config ...?

Comment: Only one `group` per call, or multiple?

Comment: If multiple groups, you might want to use something other than commandline values, such as a `yaml` or `json` file.  Just provide the file name in the commandline.

Comment: @hpaulj Yeah it seems impossible without formatted inputs as I mentioned in my answer. OP seems to be fine with formatting the input if needed.

Answer (score 2):

Seemed like a cool problem -- `argparse` lets you extend its callbacks in two ways, either with `type=...` for custom types or `action=...` with custom behaviour.  I don't think the problem as stated is possible with `type=` so I went with a solution involving `action=`

The basic approach to writing a custom action involves inheriting from `argparse.Action` and overriding `__call__` (and optionally `__init__`)

Here's a start at implementing your idea, you'll likely need to extend / change it (for instance, it might make sense to call `super().__call__(...)` in the action classes to have the base behaviour handled (for types, etc.) -- I just went with the simplest thing that worked to satisfy your question.

```py
import argparse
import pprint


class GroupAction(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        group, = values
        namespace._current_group = group
        groups = namespace.__dict__.setdefault('groups', {})
        if group in groups:
            raise argparse.ArgumentError(self, f'already specified: {group}')
        groups[group] = {}


class AppendToGroup(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        value, = values
        if not getattr(namespace, '_current_group', None):
            raise argparse.ArgumentError(self, 'outside of group!')
        namespace.groups[namespace._current_group][self.dest] = value


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--group', action=GroupAction)
parser.add_argument('--opt1', action=AppendToGroup)
parser.add_argument('--opt2', action=AppendToGroup)
parser.add_argument('--opt3', action=AppendToGroup)
pprint.pprint(parser.parse_args().groups)
```

Note here that I use the `namespace` to store state, so unfortunately at the end you'll end up with a little extra `args._current_group`.

The `__dict__.setdefault` is a bit sneaky so I'll explain it -- it's a slightly shorter way to write:

```py
if not hasattr(namespace, 'groups'):
    namespace.groups = {}
groups = namespace.groups
```

The basic strategy I used was to store the current group, and append to that group when seeing other arguments

Here's the sample in action:

```
$ python3.7 t.py --group 1 --opt1 a --opt2 b --opt3 c
{'1': {'opt1': 'a', 'opt2': 'b', 'opt3': 'c'}}
$ python3.7 t.py --group 1 --opt1 a --opt2 b --opt3 c --group 2
{'1': {'opt1': 'a', 'opt2': 'b', 'opt3': 'c'}, '2': {}}
$ python3.7 t.py --group 1 --opt1 a --opt2 b --opt3 c --group 2 --opt3 c
{'1': {'opt1': 'a', 'opt2': 'b', 'opt3': 'c'}, '2': {'opt3': 'c'}}
$ python3.7 t.py --group 1 --group 1
usage: t.py [-h] [--group GROUP] [--opt1 OPT1] [--opt2 OPT2] [--opt3 OPT3]
t.py: error: argument --group: already specified: 1
$ python3.7 t.py --opt1 a --group 1
usage: t.py [-h] [--group GROUP] [--opt1 OPT1] [--opt2 OPT2] [--opt3 OPT3]
t.py: error: argument --opt1: outside of group!
```

Comment: I like the use of an extra namespace attribute as a 'state' variable, or way of communicating between actions.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the best I could come up with, hopefully this is what you wanted.

You would need to supply the arguments in the form shown in the bottom of the code, but you mentioned this is acceptable in your post.

Namely, use `python3 script.py --group 1=2=3 --opt1 foo1=foo2=foo3 --opt2 bar1=None=bar3 --opt3 None=None=baz3` to reproduce my result.

```
import argparse, copy
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--group", default='1')
parser.add_argument("--opt1", default='foo1')
parser.add_argument("--opt2", default='bar1')
parser.add_argument("--opt3", default='baz3')
args = parser.parse_args()

def splitter(arg):
    return arg.split("=")

groups = splitter(args.group) if "=" in args.group else args.group
opt1 = splitter(args.opt1) if "=" in args.opt1 else args.opt1
opt2 = splitter(args.opt2) if "=" in args.opt2 else args.opt2
opt3 = splitter(args.opt3) if "=" in args.opt3 else args.opt3

# Dictionary with no values corresponding to just the keys in "group"
group_dict = dict.fromkeys(groups)
final_dict = copy.deepcopy(group_dict)

# Add dictionary inside each key - will remove blank keys later.
for key in group_dict:
    group_dict[key] = dict.fromkeys(['opt1', 'opt2', 'opt3'])

# Now each group_dict has form
# {'3': {'opt2': None, 'opt3': None, 'opt1': None}, '2': {'opt2': None, 'opt3': None, 'opt1': None}, '1': {'opt2': None, 'opt3': None, 'opt1': None}}
# Must use group_dict['1']['opt3'] to access 1 -> opt3 -> value
for i, key in enumerate(groups):
    group_dict[key]["opt1"] = opt1[i]
    group_dict[key]["opt2"] = opt2[i]
    group_dict[key]["opt3"] = opt3[i]

    # Remove None elements - key is main dict - key2 & value are sub dict
    final_dict[key] = {key2: value for key2, value in group_dict[key].items() if value != 'None'}

print(final_dict)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
{'1': {'opt1': 'foo1', 'opt2': 'bar1'}, '2': {'opt1': 'foo2'}, '3': {'opt2': 'bar3', 'opt3': 'baz3', 'opt1': 'foo3'}}
```

**Summary:**

1. The input can be another format if needed. **(check)**

   Use a similar format to `python3 script.py --group 1=2=3 --opt1 foo1=foo2=foo3 --opt2 bar1=None=bar3 --opt3 None=None=baz3`
2. I want to raise an error if other than (opt1, opt2, opt3) is used. **(check)**

   This will happen by default using `argparse`, you can try by using `--opt4` instead.
3. I should use argparse.ArgumentParser(). **(check)**

Comment: If you are going to downvote my answer, please consider letting me know why. I spent a lot of time on this and would appreciate knowing where I went wrong.

Comment: @xyz1.8 would appreciate an up-vote if you found this useful.